# XML Editor in java(jsp,sevlet)

Tags: java

I am developing xml editor using jsp and servlet. In this case i am using DOM parser.

I have one problem in XML editor ,
How to edit the following xml file without losing elements.
eg:

```
<book id="b1">
<bookbegin id="bb1">
<para id="p1">This is<b>first</b>line</para>
<para id="p2">This is<b>second</b>line</para>
<para id="p3">This is<b>third</b>line</para>
</bookbegin>
</book>
```

I try to edit the above xml file using dtd using jsp,servlet. but while i read the textvalue from xml, it return only first,second,third.How to read the 'This is' and 'line '. Then how to store back to the xml file using xpath.

thank in advance.

Comment: Could you make this clearer?  I can't follow what you're actually asking.

Comment: show how you are reading it (the code)

Answer (score 0):

The `<b>` tag inside the `<para>` tag is another element, not a formatting tag (in XML). Therefore, you need to traverse down to it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @JRL says, the `<b>` tags are cosnidered as well-formed XML and, as a consequence, splitted by your DOM processor.

I think youf ail to read other text elements because you only read text when an XML node has no more XML node, which is not your case here.